('Keyword argument not understood:', 'adjacency_matrix') when loading a model
I'm trying to load a Keras LTC model that has the following layers:
# Build the model.
fc_wiring = wirings.AutoNCP(100, 25)  
ltc_cell = LTCCell(fc_wiring)

 model = keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape),
        keras.layers.RNN(ltc_cell,return_sequences=True),
        keras.layers.Dense((num_classes), activation="relu")
    ]
)

This model is loaded as
    # Loading trained model
    model_path = "{}_Less_{}_LNN_{}_{}.h5.keras".format(scheme, rate, int(LNN_size), DNN_Model)
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path,custom_objects=custom_objects)

In which custom_objects is to present the layer LTCCell in the structure as "custom_objects = {'LTCCell': LTCCell}"
However, I receive the error: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'adjacency_matrix')
How can I solve this error and load the model properly?
Important: I'm using Tensorflow 2.10.0 and Keras 2.10.0 because it is the last version to support native Windows GPU

The error you're encountering, 'Keyword argument not understood:', 'adjacency_matrix', suggests that TensorFlow is having trouble understanding some custom configuration when loading your model. This often happens when TensorFlow cannot recognize the custom layer or configuration provided during model loading.When loading a Keras model that contains custom layers or objects, you need to provide a dictionary (custom_objects) to inform TensorFlow how to handle these custom components. In your case, you are using an LTCCell which seems to require custom handling.

Ensure that you define and register all necessary custom objects before loading the model. For the LTCCell, it seems you need to handle its configuration properly.Make sure that your LTCCell class (LTCCell) is properly defined and registered with Keras/TensorFlow. If it requires specific configurations or attributes, these should be properly handled within the class definition.
